# Javascript not running through for loop - cannot target div element

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to be able to remove some code when I click the x in my html. But I don't know why javascript is not looping through the code. When I do console.log it's not even running through my for loop. Can anyone help with this?

```
var removeCartButton = document.querySelector('#deletebtn');
console.log(removeCartButton); //this works in my browser

for (var i = 0; i < removeCartButton.length; i++) {
    console.log('clicked'); //doesn't work when I try to click
    var button = removeCartButton[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log('clicked');
        var buttonClicked = event.target;
        buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    })
}
```

my html code:

```
<div class="align-right" id="deletebtn">&times;</div>
```

Comment: `removeCartButton` does not have `.length` since the return value of `document.querySelector()` is `HTMLElement`. Also, there will be at most one element with a specific `id`, so why need a loop?

Comment: Got it!! thank you for clarifying, I removed the for loop, now it's working!